# Asp Mvc How to assign joined query value to viewmodel?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, type-conversion

I am working on a Asp.Net Mvc web application and i want to assign a joined linq query value to viewModel.

**ViewModel :**

```
public class BookDetails
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Book Name :")]
    public string BookName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "BookDescription :")]
    public string BookDescription { get; set; }


    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public int BookGroupId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Author Name :")]
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Book Group Name :")]
    public string BookGroupName { get; set; }

}
```

My view use multi model inside itself and i create a class to define all model and use it in controller:

**Multi Model Class :**

```
public class MultiModels
{

    public List<ApplicationUser> UserListed { get; set; }

    public List<News> LastNews { get; set; }

    public List<BookDetails> bookdetails { get; set; }


}
```

**And finally in Controller:**

```
    public IActionResult BookDetails(int id)
    {
        if (id == 0)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("NotFounds");
        }

        MultiModels model = new MultiModels();

        model.UserListed = (from u in _userManager.Users orderby u.Id descending select u).Take(10).ToList();
        model.LastNews = (from n in _context.news orderby n.NewsId descending select n).Take(5).ToList();

////////////////////////////////////////Error location
        model.bookdetails = (from b in _context.books
                             join a in _context.authors on b.AuthorID equals a.AuthorId
                             join bg in _context.bookgroups on b.BookGroupID equals bg.BookGroupId
                             where b.BookId == id
                             select new
                             {
                                 b.BookId,
                                 b.BookDescription,
                                 b.BookName,
                                 b.AuthorID,
                                 b.BookGroupID,
                                 a.AuthorName,
                                 bg.BookGroupName
                             }).ToList();

        ////////////////////////////////////////

        return View(model);
    }
```

but in the joined query, the following error occurs:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collection.Generic.List<<anonymous type:int Bookid, string BookDescription, string BookName, int AuthorID, int BookGroupID, string AuthorName, string BookGroupName>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<yourProject.Models.ViewModels.BookDetails>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select new BookDetails
{
    BookId = b.BookId,
    BookDescription = b.BookDescription,
    BookName = b.BookName,
    AuthorId = b.AuthorID,
    BookGroupId = b.BookGroupID,
    AuthorName = a.AuthorName,
    BookGroupName = bg.BookGroupName
}).ToList();
```

Change the select to the code above. Your select is create a new Anonymous type when your model is expecting a type of `List<BookDetails>`.